# Better to store array in localstorage or many variables?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Take for example a case where I have thousands of students.

So I'd have an array of objects.

```
students = [

{ "name":"mickey", "id","1" },
{ "name":"donald", "id","2" }
{ "name":"goofy", "id","3" }
...

];
```

The way I currently save this into my localstorage is:

```
localStorage.setItem('students', JSON.stringify(students));
```

And the way I retrieve this from the localstorage is:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('students');
students = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now, whenever I make a change to a single student, I must save ALL the
students to the localStorage.

```
students[0].name = "newname";
localStorage.setItem('students', JSON.stringify(students));
```

I was wondering if it'd be better instead of keeping an array, to maybe have
thousands of variables

```
localStorage.setItem('student1', JSON.stringify(students[0]));
localStorage.setItem('student2', JSON.stringify(students[1]));
localStorage.setItem('student3', JSON.stringify(students[2]));
...
```

That way a student can get saved individually without saving the rest?

I'll potentially have many "students".. Thousands. So which way is better,
array or many variables inside the localstorage?

Note: I know I should probably be using IndexedDB, but I need to use LocalStorage for now. Thanks

Comment: You know LocalStorage is not really persistent right?

Comment: localStorage is persistent, sessionStorage is not

Comment: @foreyez why save data in localStorage on every change? it will be better do this in window.onclose event

Comment: localStorage IS persistent (as long as not cleared by user) - but thats right, you do have to resave it every time unless you use different keys. if you use different keys in the way you want to, might as well use Indexed DB. Or, you have to use different keys in the way you gave in your example student1, student2, etc. which means you potentially still have to have one key called students which is always updated with student1, student2, etc. when a new one is added, and removed when one is removed. Gets hairy without db when you want db type features.

Comment: @kirugan Yeah persistent until the user decides to clear his cache  :P

Comment: @PeeHaa yeah but i think foreyez already save it in db on server ;)

Comment: That's what I am hoping at least

Comment: pretty sure best you can do is what you said: student1, student2, student 3, etc. separate keys and values, and also have one more **list of keys** key called "students" that says just "student1, student2, student3" in order to be able to retrieve entire table and iterate through those keys to be able to get those corresponding entries in the localStorage. You have to remember if you add and remove to also update the students **list of keys** key as well besides the actual add and remove then.

Comment: but its easier to store it in one key and in your case its better to do that than to split them up.

Comment: @kirugan the reason why is b/c i didn't want the changes to disappear on browser refresh... but mb you're right as far as window.onclose

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case it would probably be easier to store the students in one localStorage key and using JSON parse to reconstruct your object, add to it, then stringifying it again and it would be easier than splitting it up by each student to different keys.

If you don't have so many data layers that you **really** need a real local database like IndexedDB, a single key and a JSON string value is probably OK for your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation for the size of local storage and older browsers won't support it.

It is better to store in an array for couple reasons:

- Can use loops to process them
- No JSON needed
- Always growable

Comment: And how will he save it between page refreshes? He is already storing data in an array and saving it to localStorage for persistency.

Comment: He is modifying the local storage whenever anything changes. He only need to sync during page refresh.